# Is it possible to deactivate addeventlistener (mouseover/mouseout) on a specific condition in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, svg, hover, mouseover, mouseout

```
let currentColor = 0

function makeHover () {
        console.log(currentColor);
            svgAll.forEach(item => {
                item.addEventListener('mouseover', event => {
                    event.target.style.fill = "rgb(168,168,168)";
                    event.target.style.pointerEvents = "all";
                    event.target.style.cursor = "pointer";
                    event.target.style.strokeOpacity = "1";
                    event.target.style.fillOpacity = "0.3";
                    event.target.style.transitionDuration = "0.5s";
                    event.target.style.transitionTimingFunction = "ease-in";
                })
            })

            svgAll.forEach(item => {
                item.addEventListener('mouseout', event => {
                    event.target.style.fill = "none";
                    event.target.style.stroke = "white";
                    event.target.style.pointerEvents = "all";
                    event.target.style.strokeOpacity = "1";
                    event.target.style.fillOpacity = "0.1";
                    event.target.style.transitionDuration = "0.5s";
                    event.target.style.transitionTimingFunction = "ease-out";
                })
            })
        }
```

In this Code I only want to enable the hover effect when:

```
if (currentColor === 0)
        {makeHover ()}
```

I am using this effect on an SVG and the console gives
`currentColor = 1` when another condition is met that is setting `currentColor = 1`. Still the hovering works when `currentColor = 1`, is it even possible to deactivate the hover effect ones activated?

Comment: Why not change the settings with a `:hover` rule for a specific class and only toggle that class?

Comment: Add the `if()` in the event handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to wrap the styling in `if` statements:

```js
svgAll.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('mouseover', event => {
    if (currentColor === 0) {
      event.target.style.fill = "none";
      event.target.style.stroke = "white";
      event.target.style.pointerEvents = "all";
      event.target.style.strokeOpacity = "1";
      event.target.style.fillOpacity = "0.1";
      event.target.style.transitionDuration = "0.5s";
      event.target.style.transitionTimingFunction = "ease-out";
    }
  })
})
svgAll.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('mouseout', event => {
    if (currentColor === 0) {
      event.target.style.fill = "none";
      event.target.style.stroke = "white";
      event.target.style.pointerEvents = "all";
      event.target.style.strokeOpacity = "1";
      event.target.style.fillOpacity = "0.1";
      event.target.style.transitionDuration = "0.5s";
      event.target.style.transitionTimingFunction = "ease-out";
    }
  })
})
```